# Retrieving artifacts created by a remote trigger

Tags: jenkins

We have an issue with some software (Redgate SQL Packager) that we rely on for our build process, notably that we have a license to run it on one machine (our old build machine running FinalBuilder) and the company doesn't sell it anymore to allow us to also run it on our new build machine (running Jenkins).

To get around this, we have installed a second Jenkins server on the old machine that will have a single job running SQL Packager on the old build machine and publish the output (a single .exe) as an artifact. The intention is to trigger this from the main build using Parameterized Remote Trigger plugin and then to copy the artifact back to the main Jenkins server for publishing.

I am, however, running into issues that it is more difficult to retrieve this artifact than I was expecting. I had hoped to use the Copy Artifact plugin, but this only seems to want to use local build projects. I couldn't see anything obvious on the plugins list, either.

- Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a simpler way of solving this (running a single build step that MUST be run on a specific machine)
- Am I using artifacts in the right way?
- I'm worried that there is potential for race conditions - I'd ideally like to know the build ref of my remote build so I can be sure that I'm getting the correct artifact, however the plugin seems to restrict me to 'most recent' which is surely dangerous with concurrent builds?
- And if everything else is fine - how do I retrieve this file from my remote build machine?

Comment: There's a command line for packager that can be downloaded from here: https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-packager/ However, you will need to generate the script itself with SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare, that are very much supported.

Comment: Have you considered the Redgate Jenkins plugin? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Redgate+SQL+CI+Plugin

Comment: @DavidAtkinson No, hadn't even thought of looking for one. Looking at it, I think we're running something that pre-dates this (it was released in 2008 and the product line has already been retired). In the end we've been able to use the software via the command line in the same way as the FinalBuilder server is doing, it's just the calling process must be on the same machine as the installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a separate Jenkins server, connect to the old machine as a build slave from your Jenkins master, see [Distributed Builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) for various connection options. Define the SQL Packager build in Jenkins so that it is tied to run on the build slave on the old machine. Once the builds are controlled by a single master, you can use the [Copy Artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin).

Regarding the "race condition" issue, the Copy Artifact plugin allows you to choose from several options for selecting the build to copy artifacts from -- you can choose the latest successful build, the last build marked "keep forever", a particular build, and others. There are a number of ways to set up the jobs so that you select a known good build, you might find the [Promoted Builds plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) useful.

Comment: Ended up doing it using this method, very simple to set up in the end and possible to restrict this build step to the machine with the required build software installed. The CopyToSlave plugin deals with copying the artifact back to the originator, though the other information on artifact plugins are useful for future info